# How to replace the inner HTML of a div with text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below in the HTML, rendered in page.

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<span class="breadcrumb-trail" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content"><a title="" href="/default.aspx" target="_self">Home</a> &gt; <a title="" href="/summary.aspx?sid=105&amp;pid=133" target="_self">Summary</a></span>
</div>
```

On document ready function, I have to replace

```
<a title="" href="/summary.aspx?sid=105&amp;pid=133" target="_self">Summary</a>
```

with

```
Summary
```

So that the HTML is changed to following :

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<span class="breadcrumb-trail" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content"><a title="" href="/default.aspx" target="_self">Home</a> &gt; Summary</span>
</div>
```

How can i do this with jQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content a:last-child').text();
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content a:last-child').remove();
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content').append(text);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SB48A/1/)**

Or you can use:

```
 var text = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content a:last-child').text();
 $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content a:last-child').replaceWith(text);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SB48A/)**

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/B4CrS/

Your Ids look like user control Visual studio generated you could do this simply!

This will fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').filter(function (index) {
       if ($(this).text() === "Summary")
           $(this).replaceWith('Summary');
        return $(this).text() === "Summary";
    });

});
```

Comment: And why a downvote care to explain please? `:))` Random downvotes dont help! and demotivating `:P` siiiigh!

Answer (score 1):

use [jQuery.replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
var node = $(".breadcrumb-trail > a:last-child");
var text = node.text();
node.replaceWith( text );
```

You can change the selector based on your need. Current selector selects the last child "a" inside element with breadcrumb-trail class.

Comment: +1, yes and I wonder why no one can see that the html id is usercontrol code hence using it will not fix OP's issue `:)` there is another way using filter I have shown below. **But I am no Downvoter** `:)` just to be clear!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.breadcrumb-trail a:contains("Summary")').replaceWith('Summary');
```

or

```
$(".breadcrumb-trail a").last().replaceWith('Summary');
```

could work, if you want it shorter.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/erpEN/

Answer (score -1):

Consider using thttp://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_bc_content").html("Summary")
}
```